# How to add a material output node?

Tags: materials, node-editor

Yesterday I was following a couch making tutorial and when I clicked on "Use Nodes" in the Node Editor there was a node called "Material Output". Today I am trying to achieve the same thing with a sphere, but no "Material Output" node pops up just some "Output" node. 
 Thanks in advance! 
[image: No Material Output]
[image: There is a Material Output node]

Comment: Oh my god thank you for pointing that out. +1000 rep :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to switch the render engine you are using:

[image: Change Render Engine]

The nodes are very different between Cycles and Blender Intrenal materials, so you will notice a lot of incompatibilities if you are in the wrong one.

Comment: Also, you will need to add the "Materials Output" node manually after changing the render (to Cycles Renderer). Add it with Shift-A. Under the menu "Output", "Material Output" should be present. Remove the old "Output" node by mark and DEL.